# SSH keys inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

I have a script that connects to gitlab, how do I properly transfer it to a container so that it can connect to gitlab by SSH?

```
   if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH_SAVE_SCHEMA, '.git')):
        repo = Repo.init(PATH_SAVE_SCHEMA)
        origin = repo.create_remote('origin', GIT_REMOTE_URL)
        config_writer = repo.config_writer()
        config_writer.set_value('user', 'name', GIT_USER_NAME)
        config_writer.set_value('user', 'email', GIT_USER_EMAIL)
        config_writer.set_value('http', 'sslverify', 'false')
        config_writer.release()
        origin.fetch()
        origin.pull(repo.refs[0].remote_head)
        repo.git.reset('--hard')
    else:
        repo = Repo(PATH_SAVE_SCHEMA)
        repo.git.reset('--hard')
        repo.remote('origin').pull('master')
```

Now my container is going, but it gives an error

```
Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
cmdline: git pull -v origin master
stderr: 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.'
```

How to specify the command for the key in the Docker file?
Do I need to enter the key in the GitLab repository?

My docker file:

```
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG SSH_PUBLIC_KEY
ARG SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "${SSH_PUBLIC_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN echo "${SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS}" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to safely include credentials for something like this in a Dockerfile; it's better to run commands like this from the host.  As a developer, I'd also be surprised if the `docker build` sequence tried switching to a different branch instead of just building what I already had checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Your not providing a password anywhere.

The quick-and-dirty way to do it is to specify your password in the git url:

`<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git`

But then your password will be in your code in cleartext. The proper way to go around is in [to mount your secret as volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), i.e. a password.txt file.

Even better would be to use an `ssh_key` and mount that as a volume.

Comment: Because now the script is running on the host and access is on the SSH key, but I don’t know how to drop this key into the container

Answer (score 0):

During build image you can copy your ssh key to some "tmp" build stage, download code from git and in "main" build stage copy that code from "tmp" stage.

See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

At the end image should not have any information about ssh key in inspection.